# error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token (Template compilation issue)

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create my own templated List class as a practice excercise. I should have probably started smaller but there you go.. i'm getting the error **"expected unqualified-id before '<' token " at each line that reads:**

```
typedef <typename ListType>
```

I'm a student and I've been reading up on templates for a couple of hours but still cant figure this one out, any help would be much appreciated!

My hpp file for List:

```
#if !defined _LIST_HPP_
#define _LIST_HPP_

#include "Node.hpp"

///since we're creating a template everything must be defined in the hpp

typedef <typename ListType>
class List
{
   public:
      List();
      bool Empty();
      void PushFront();
      void PushBack();
      void PopBack();
      Node<ListType>& GetHead();

   private:
      int _size;
      Node<ListType>* _head;
      Node<ListType>* _tail;
};


///implement List class here
typedef <typename ListType>
List<ListType>::List() : _head(0), _tail(0), _size(0)
{
}
typedef <typename ListType>
bool <ListType>Empty()
{
   return !_size; //returns true if size = 0
}
typedef <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::PushFront()
{
   _head = new Node<ListType>( _head , 0 );
   if (!Empty())
      _head->_prev->_next = _head; //set previous nodes _next to new _head

   ++_size;
}
typedef <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::PushBack()
{
   _tail = new Node<ListType>( 0 , _tail);
   if (!Empty())
      _tail->_next->_prev = _tail; // set old tails _prev to new tail

   ++_size;
}
typedef <typename ListType>
void List<ListType>::PopBack()
{

}
typedef <typename ListType>
Node<ListType>& List<ListType>::GetHead()
{
   return _head;
}

#endif //define
```

And i'll also include the templated node class hpp incase it could be something there that's throwing things off?

```
#if !defined _NODE_HPP_
#define _NODE_HPP_


//#include "Sprite.hpp"

template<typename NodeType>
class Node{
   public:
      Node( Node* prev = 0, Node* next = 0);
      void SetData(NodeType newData);
      void GetData();
   private:
      friend class List;

      NodeType _data;
      Node* _next;
      Node* _prev;

};


///implement Node

template <typename NodeType>
Node<NodeType>::Node(Node* prev, Node* next) : _prev(prev), _next(next)
{}
template <typename NodeType>
void Node<NodeType>::SetData(NodeType newData)
{
   _data = newData;
}
template <typename NodeType>
void Node<NodeType>::GetData()
{
   return _data;
}

#endif //define
```

Comment: In one file you use `template` and in the other `typedef`... Some failed replace-all maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s `template`, not `typedef`.

And while we’re at it, your preprocessor tokens are invalid identifiers since they start with an underscore, which isn’t allowed here. Use something like `LIST_HPP` instead.

Finally, let’s take a look at your `Empty` definition:

```
typedef <typename ListType>
bool <ListType>Empty()
{
   return !_size; //returns true if size = 0
}
```

First of all, this is missing the class name in the method name. Secondly, I dislike the conversion from a number to `bool`. Why not use an explicit comparison? That also obviates the comment, which is useless in itself since it merely paraphrases the code.

This leaves us with:

```
template <typename ListType>
bool List<ListType>::Empty()
{
    return _size != 0;
}
```

Comment: oh lordy how embarassing. Okay i've got it now, and thanks for all the input on the rest of the code! Really helpful. Will make the corrections and remember your comments.

Comment: I know it might be inappropriate to ask about an additional error here but since you've already looked through my code.. I'm getting the error: template argument required for 'struct List', on the line i declare my Node class in Node.hpp. Any ideas? I thought i had a reasonable understanding of templates but all the syntax keeps catching me up. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Holly Hm, it’s not obvious from the current code what might be causing that error, especially since at the time of declaration of `Node` there should be no mention of `List` yet, right? Better ask a new question for that.